# How to get full file path when uploading file in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the full file path when uploading a file.

```
<input type="file" id="filename" />
```

How can i get the full file path name by using JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: what have you done so far regarding code ?

Comment: You can't. For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path.

Comment: A website should never need to know anything about the file system structure of the user's computer.

Comment: (Before my edit you said…) "javascript or jquery"? jQuery is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JavaScript. You can use "JavaScript" and you can use "JavaScript with jQuery", but you can't use "jQuery without JavaScript".

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean the full path as it is on the user's machine. It is generally impossible to get this, for all kinds of very good security reasons. No website has any good reason to know what my file system looks like.

Most browsers will give you a path like `C:\fakepath\realfilename.ext`.

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-value):

> **filename**
>
> On getting, it must return the string "C:\fakepath\" followed by the filename of the first file in the list of selected files, if any, or the empty string if the list is empty. On setting, if the new value is the empty string, it must empty the list of selected files; otherwise, it must throw an INVALID_STATE_ERR exception.

Comment: In firefox10.0  i am getting only file name. How can i get full file path name in firefox also.

Comment: To my surprise, FF10 doesn't follow the spec here. Nevertheless, you cannot get the full path name. Stop trying.